# Highlighting _source excluded fields in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, highlight

I've a question in Elasticsearch highlighting. Am setting the mapping of an index in such a way that some of the fields need not be stored in elasticsearch.

For eg :-

```
PUT employee/_mapping/records
{
  "_source": {
        "includes": [
          "id",
          "name"
        ],
        "excludes": [
         "designation",
         "age"
        ]
      }
}
```

Now,I'm able to search the excluded fields. But I can't highlight fields  that are excluded from `_source`.
I've read this in elasticsearch documentation. But I want to confirm whether there's any way to highlight fields in such a scenario. Thanks

Comment: The same documentation says that you can store the fields and you should be able to highlight them: _In order to perform highlighting, the actual content of the field is required. If the field in question is stored (has store set to true in the mapping) it will be used, otherwise, the actual _source will be loaded and the relevant field will be extracted from it._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From further research, I came to know that we should either store the field in ES by giving `store : yes` or it should be included in `_source` field of ES to highlight it in searches.